# How does R ggplot2 get the column names via aes?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I understand *how to use* aes, but I don't understand the programmatic paradigm.

When I use ggplot, assuming I have a data.frame with column names "animal" and "weight", I can do the following.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=weight)) + facet_grid(~animal) + geom_histogram()
```

What I don't understand is that weight and animal are not supposed to be strings, they are just typed out as is. How is it I can do that? It should be something like this instead:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x='weight')) + facet_grid('~animal') + geom_histogram()
```

I don't "declare" weight or animal as vectors anywhere? This seems to be... really unusual? Is this like a macro or something where it gets aes "whole," looks into df for its column names, and then fills in the gaps where it sees those variable names in aes?

I guess what I would like is to see some similar function in R which can take variables which are not declared in the scope, and the name of this feature, so I can read further and maybe implement my own similar functions.

Comment: I'd recommend checking out these vignettes. They're more based around `dplyr`'s NSE, but they both talk about the idea that R can evaluate arguments in different enviroments. https://rpubs.com/lionel-/programming-draft. https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: Are you familiar with the other `tidyverse` packages? They generally work this way, taking a data frame, passing it along subsequent functions, and operating on columns based on quosures. [Here's another tutorial](https://edwinth.github.io/blog/nse/) that's helped me wrap my head around this

Comment: This isn't so unusual--it's the same for base R functions. E.g., `plot(mpg~hp,data=mtcars)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `R` this is called non-standard evaluation. There is a [chapter on non-standard evaluation in R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) in the Advanced R book available free online. Basically R can look at the the call stack to see the symbol that was passed to the function rather than just the value that symbol points to. It's used a lot in base R. And it's used in a slightly different way in the tidyverse which has a formal class called a quosure to make this stuff easier to work with.

These methods are great for interactive programming. They save keystrokes and clutter, but if you make functions that are too dependent on that function, they become difficult to script or include in other functions.

The formula syntax (the one with the `~`) probably the safest and more programatic way to work with symbols. It captures symbols that can be later evaluated in the context of a data.frame with functions like `model.frame()`. And there are build in functions to help manipulate formulas like `update()` and `reformulate`.

And since you were explicitly interested in the `aes()` call, you can get the source code for any function in R just by typing it's name without the quotes. With `ggplot2_2.2.1`, the function looks like this

```
aes
# function (x, y, ...) 
# {
#     aes <- structure(as.list(match.call()[-1]), class = "uneval")
#     rename_aes(aes)
# }
# <environment: namespace:ggplot2>
```

The newest version of ggplot uses different `rlang` methods to be more consistent with other tidyverse libraries so it looks a bit different.

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I wanted. Surprising how hard it was to search for this answer on google, as if you don't know what it is, it is so weird it's hard to formulate a query on it, and most of the results just tell you how to use ggplot. Thanks again!